# In electrostatics, $\nabla\times\mathbf E=0$. Why is this?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields, conservative-field

I can understand why this is *mathematically* but I do not understand the actual *why*, like in words why this is.

Comment: The odd thing with your question is that there is nothing mathematically making this true. That is, not purely from math. If you start with Coulomb's law, for example, then it falls out nicely. But then you had to go beyond math and bring in some experimentally validated physics.

Answer (score 6):

If the curl of a static electric field were nonzero, you could move a point charge around a closed circuit and it would have more energy when it got back to its starting point than it did when it was there last time.  This would be a violation of conservation of energy.

Comment: Technically it would be a violation of the electrostatic interaction being conservative. If the electrostatic interaction were not conservative, then we would just take that into account and energy conservation would be fine.

Comment: @AaronStevens yeah, but the energy would still have to come from somewhere, and with a static electric field created by a fixed charge distribution, what would that source be?  I suppose you could make something up--the number of possible ways things could be different from how they actually are is infinite--but outside of that, conservation of energy requires the force be conservative, and as such is a more fundamental reason than just saying the force is conservative, which is pretty circular.

Comment: So $\nabla\times\mathbf E=0$ can be derived just from energy conservation? Energy conservation implies a conservative electrostatic field? (also, I didn't down vote).

Comment: @AaronStevens sure, in the case of static electric field, and assuming you're willing to concede that moving a test charge around doesn't somehow suck energy out of the charge distribution responsible for that field.

Comment: I suppose I'm being too picky. Thanks for the chat.

Comment: *assuming you're willing to concede that moving a test charge around doesn't somehow suck energy out of the charge distribution responsible for that field.* This is kind of the definition of a test charge: inserting it doesn't change the ambient field enough to matter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in short, there is no deeper understanding as to why the curl of the electric field is zero. The Maxwell equations are the most basic laws of electrodynamics and when you constrain yourself to the static case, that the curl of the electric field vanishes is one of the statements of the Maxwell equations.

However, you can try to better understand this law by studying it in different equivalent formulations. For example, within electrostatics, Coloumb's law and the Maxwell equations are equivalent. Thus, you can see the vanishing curl of the electric field as an aspect of the Coloumb's law if you wish. This is easy to intuit. Any configuration of electric fields can be imagined to be conjured up via superposing multiple point electric charges (either of finite or infinite charge density). Since the electric field of a point charge is radial, its curl is trivially zero. Since the curl is a linear operator, the curl of the superposition of various electric fields whose curls are zero is also zero.

But, in the end, I would say that this description is really just a way to intuit. In the larger context, the Maxwell equations are the most basic principles of electrodynamics and thus, it is in vain to "explain" them in terms of some other results of electrodynamics.

Comment: *there is no deeper understanding as to why the curl of the electric field is zero.* Ben51's answer is a counterexample to this claim. *The Maxwell equations are the most basic laws of electrodynamics* There are various ways to derive them from considerations that are arguably more fundamental. And even if we don't set out to derive them from more fundamental principles, there are lots of constraints on their form.

Comment: @BenCrowell I agree that there are various constraints on them. But, to demand that electric field be conservative is literally no explanation at all as to why its curl is zero. It is literally a restatement. So no, the "answer" you cite is not a counter example to my claim.

Comment: @BenCrowell Based on your comments on both answers it seems like this post would benefit from an answer by you. I've never heard of deriving Maxwell's equations from anything deeper, or maybe I just don't view the derivations I have seen in the same way you do.